# How can I have TV shows I'm not currently watching not appear on the iPad?

Tags: itunes, ipad, television

I recently upgraded from iOS 6 to 8. Previously, the show's icon did not appear in the video viewer if there were no shows uploaded to the iPad. Now, they all show, presumably so that you can download cloud versions at any time.

I would like to only have shows I'm currently watching show up on the iPad. The screen is cluttered with more and more shows, but I don't want to delete the downloaded tv files completely from my iTunes drive.

Is there a way to mark shows visible/not visible?

Comment: What video viewer? is this an app?

Comment: @Tyson only the native `Videos` application in iOS can show purchased, but not downloaded, iTunes video content.

Answer (score 1):

In the `Settings` application on your iPad go to the `iTunes & App Store` settings and turn the `SHOW ALL Videos` setting to `Off`. This show you only downloaded content, not all your purchased and iTunes Match content, in the `Video` app.

[image]

Comment: You rock. I'll give it a try.